How to set the height attribute of a face with a variable?
I mostly use Emacs on GNU/Linux Arch, and here is how I usually set fonts:
    (use-package cus-face :ensure nil
      :config
      (custom-set-faces
       '(default ((t (:family "Source Code Pro" :foundry "ADBO" :slant normal :weight normal :height 180 :width normal)))))
      (custom-theme-set-faces
       'user
       '(variable-pitch ((t (:family "Open Sans" :height 180))))
       '(fixed-pitch ((t (:family "Source Code Pro"))))
       '(org-table ((t (:inherit fixed-pitch 0.85))))
       '(org-block ((t (:inherit fixed-pitch 0.9))))
       )
      )

However, when I use Emacs on Windows 10, the fonts are too big, so the height should be 120 instead of 180.
I would like Emacs to automatically set height to 120 when on Win, and 180 when on Linux.
I tried the following:
(defvar is-linux (string= system-type "gnu/linux"))
(defvar is-win (string= system-type "windows-nt"))

(when is-win (setq custom-font-size "120"))
(when is-linux (setq custom-font-size "180"))

(use-package cus-face :ensure nil
  :config
  (custom-set-faces
   '(default ((t (:family "Source Code Pro" :foundry "ADBO" :slant normal :weight normal :height custom-font-size :width normal)))))
  (custom-theme-set-faces
   'user
   '(variable-pitch ((t (:family "Open Sans" :height custom-font-size))))
   '(fixed-pitch ((t (:family "Source Code Pro"))))
   '(org-table ((t (:inherit fixed-pitch 0.85))))
   '(org-block ((t (:inherit fixed-pitch 0.9))))
   )
    )

But I have the following error message Error (use-package): cus-face/:config: Default face height not absolute and positive: custom-font-size
How could I set the value of :height with a variable?

What do you mean "height defconst"?  You've used the word defconst twice, and I can't figure out why -- despite the title, your question doesn't appear to be related to defconst at all, but rather about setting face attributes.

You need to backquote the expression: quoting it means that nothing inside it is evaluated. Then you need to use , in front of custom-font-size to make sure that it is evaluated. This is a FAQ and it has many duplicates. See the canonical answer in the link above.

@phils For what I understand, in cus-face.el, :height is defined as an attribute of defconst custom-face-attributes

Thanks a lot @NickD, '(variable-pitch ((t `(:family "Open Sans" :height ,custom-font-size)))) did the trick.

Every expression that includes custom-font-size in this case: the expression that defines the default face in custom-set-faces and the expression that defined the variable-pitch face in custom-theme-set-faces. E.g (custom-set-faces `(default ( ... :height ,custom-font-size ...))))).

"'(variable-pitch ((t `(:family "Open Sans" :height ,custom-font-size)))) did the trick": no, it does not. You need to change the quote to a backquote: (custom-theme-set-faces ... `(variable-pitch ((t (:family "Open Sans" :height ,custom-font-size)))).

You're completely right it didn't do the trick, I spoke too fast. It just evaluated the code without errors, but the height wasn't 180 nor 120. With the ` in the proper place as you showed me it worked perfectly. Thank you again!
